# Is using ord() wrong in this case?

Tags: python, if-statement, append, ord

I'm solving a codewar question - there are two groups containing characters with their own power (A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 . . . Z = 26). Strings consist of uppercase letters only. As only two groups fight against each other, group whose total power (A + B + C ...) is bigger wins. If the powers are equal, it's a tie.

I just converted x and y into lists and used ord() to convert the characters into numbers. And I compared the sum of their numbers using if statements. However, my code still makes a few errors (passed: 103    failed: 5). What is a problem in my code?

Here is my code...

def battle(x, y):

```
z = []

for a in x:
    z.append(ord(a))
    
first_group = sum(z)

p = []

for b in y:
    p.append(ord(b))
    
second_group = sum(p)

if first_group > second_group:
    return x

elif first_group < second_group:
    return y

else:
    return "Tie!"
```

Comment: There's simpler ways to do it, but I don't offhand see why this wouldn't work.  I take it you don't have access to the test data?

Comment: Are you sure that the string `"Tie!"` is what you're supposed to return in the event of a tie?

Comment: maybe bultibyte chars? but i would expect even that to work

Comment: @JoranBeasley that would be a consideration in Python 2, but in Python 3 `ord` will fail on non-Unicode characters.

Comment: ahh yeah :P Im still getting used to some changes :P

Answer (score 1):

No, using `ord()` is perfectly fine in this case provided you use it correctly :-)

Assuming the conditions are as you state (`x` and `y` being an iterable collection (string, list, etc) of uppercase letters), that will work but it's *only* guaranteed for teams of the same size.

By that, I mean a team of twenty-five `A` units (score = 25) *should* lose to a team of one `Z` unit (score = 26).

But, because you're implicitly increasing the score by `ord('A') - 1` for each unit, that won't work. With `ord('A')` being 65, the A team gets a score of 1625, while the Z team gets 90.

The score you use has to be constructed for the *actual* scores of each unit, something like (making the calculation a little more succinct in the process):

```py
first_group = sum((ord(item) - ord('A') + 1 for item in a))
```

That would make your code along the lines of:

```py
def battle(x, y):
    first = sum((ord(item) - ord('A') + 1 for item in x))
    second = sum((ord(item) - ord('A') + 1 for item in y))

    if first > second:
        return x
    if second > first:
        return y
    return "Tie!"
```

Comment: Use (...) instead of [...] because generators are more efficient than lists.

Comment: @MarkRansom at least in this case ;P

Comment: @JoranBeasley I'm hard pressed to come up with a case where that wouldn't be true.  Any function that takes an iterable wouldn't care if it gets a generator or a list, and building a list only to throw it away immediately is just wasteful.

Comment: i think if you only need to iterate it once your right ... i think if you have to convert it to a list anyway `[x for x [1,2,3,5,]]` is faster than `list((x for x in [1,2,3,4,5]))` ... I think i remember that ... i might be wrong and im not gonna bother checking right now ... eitherway the difference is pretty minimal in most cases

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the actual mapping. For example, 'AA' is 2 and 'Z' is 26 so 'AA' < 'Z' but your solution has 'AA' = 130 and 'Z' = 90 so 'AA' > 'Z'.

You can get there by subtracting `ord('A')` to get the relative number and adding one:

```
ord(a) - ord('A') + 1
```